# Error while putting power format in placeholder

Tags: css, number-formatting, placeholder

This is i am using for placeholder in html for input text.

```html
 <input type="text" required  class="form-control ta num " name="totalarea" id="totalarea" placeholder="Área Total (m&sup2;)">
<p class="ttp_txt1" id="totarep">Área Total (m&sup2;)</p>
```

and this is i am using for jquery placeholder.

$('#totalarea').attr("placeholder", "Área Total (m²)");

$('#totalarea').append("placeholder", "Área Total (m²)");

Above code looking perfect when i directly copy paste m square.

[current design for power in the placeholder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DyD0U.png)

these are two ways i have used for make power as placeholder
Área Total (m²)
Área Total (m²)
but when i edit something on page and upload it then it's shows diamonds in the place of power(i.e. m raise to 2).

[error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mb2uz.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can't directly write `Área Total (m²) Área Total (m²)` in your html code. you must convert the special characters.

try to write like this to your code

`&Aacute;rea Total (m&sup2;) &Aacute;rea Total (m&sup2;)`

[Here link the converter](http://www.web2generators.com/html-based-tools/online-html-entities-encoder-and-decoder)

Comment: its not about converting special characters "Á".Even if i put Area Total (m&sup2;) in placeholder it will show correctly.But after some time it will show diamond instead of square (i.e. 2) m².

Comment: can you give snippet of your code? So, I can check the error

Comment: Please check i have added snippet.

Comment: I don't know what you need. Show all your code which showing the error.  I tried to change placeholder with jquery this work fine https://jsfiddle.net/vz1xjoue/1/

Comment: see what i am doing...i am changing placeholder on drop down selection..so when i select particular option..placeholder will change and that placeholder is in power format i.e. m raise to 2 and v raise to 2.